# How to hide console error messages in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How to hide console error messages in Angular JS?
My web apps is works, no bug!!!! but it has a lot of error message in console.

thanks

Update: I just fix my bug, but this bug can't fix.............anyidea...THX
[image]

Comment: there are bugs, there's 9+ your getting them errors as the object is not defined (yet), so you should pre-define your vars ready for the promise/resolve

Comment: All those errors mean you have bugs. You just haven't seen them yet. Instead of being foolish and hiding the warnings and errors, fix them. It's simply dumb to ignore them, hide your head in the sand, and hope everything works out in the end. Pretending the problem does not exist is ridiculous, and thinking *it seems to work, so no bugs even if I get lots of errors* is absolutely the wrong thing to do.

Comment: It does not throw errors if there is nothing wrong with it, make sure you are handling `undefined` variables inside those involved functions `if ($scope.somethingvar === undefined) return;` to prevent it from misbehaving, This issues frequently occur during startup when `$scope.somethingvar` is not yet defined, yet the function was called.

Comment: Thanks All!!!! I just fix all of the ".length" and "slice" bug!!! but this bug I can't fix i....Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10.....

Comment: I upload the new  image form question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like most of the errors you show in your screenshot stem from the same issue - namely, attempting to call `.length` on an object that does not exist.

If you expect the object to not exist sometimes, then you should fix the source of that error with something like:

`if (object.length) { ... do something with .length property ... }`

Errors should not be ignored! They're our only window into understanding when our programs are not behaving as we intend.